# In Knockoutjs whats the difference between a function and an object based viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a difference between creating a viewmodel like so:

```
var viewmodel = {
  firstName: ko.observable(),
  lastName: ko.observable()
}
```

and:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
  this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
}

viewModel = new Person('john', 'doe');
```

I'm asking because I'm trying to add a prototype function to the first way and its not letting me. Like so:

```
viewModel.prototype.toJSON = function () { .. }
```

Browser complains that prototype is undefined. I'm just trying to do what [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html) is showing.. but I'm having this problem.  And I'm thinking its because of the differences in how I'm creating my viewmodel.  Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about it is that using the first approach, you can only have one single instance of the object, so prototype wouldn't make much sense. To add a toJSON method to it, you can just define it as viewmodel.toJSON = function () { ; };

With the second approach, you can have multiple instances of Person, with different property values. prototype allows you to add your toJSON function to all instances of Person.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense

Comment: I was wondering how I can manage 'this' when keeping the viewmodel as a javascript object as opposed to a function definition? I tried `self: this,' but it doesn't seem to work appropriately.